# Aegir redirect url to actual site

Tags: redirection, aegir

I’d like to redirect the: `aegir-server.com/a-site-url.com` to `a-site-url.com` without hacking Aegir and based on a pattern so any future site will follow this type of redirect. Is it possible through Aegir?

(Aegir redirects the : aegir-server.com/node/site_id/goto_site to the site, but this is not what I need)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to edit the .htaccess file of your hostmaster platform and add something like

`RewriteRule ^(.*\.com) http://$1 [L,R=301]`

Note that you have to reload apache as Aegir integrates the htaccess file into the vhost config.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. I was looking for a more 'Drupal/Aegir' way, but probably I'll use the .htaccess as it's the million tested solution.

Comment: The .htaccess of the hostmaster platform may get lost when upgrading Aegir (ex: Debian packages). You could also use https://github.com/mlutfy/provision_customhtaccess/ (but you would have to restrict it to only the Hostmaster platform, especially if you do not fully trust users on that system, since they could inject bad things in the vhost).